# Can I use static images for lottie instead of a json file?

Tags: ios, json, swift, png, lottie

While `lottie` is used to animate images based on a `json` file, I'm in a situation in my project where I may suddenly have a static image (`png` or whatever) instead. So my question is, how do I make it accept and display a static image?

With a `json` file, you do it like this:

```
lot?.animation = Animation.named(res) //res == json file name
lot?.play()
```

Now it can't accept image names like this (res being the name of the png); it doesn't show anything at all. So how would I go about displaying the image properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lottie behaviour does not accept static images, only accepts json coded animations, my recommendation is to put some UIImage same size as the AnimationView and do some hide-unhide.